# Python isn't running openai script after installing it with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having an issue with my terminal while trying to run the openai scripts.
I install it using `pip install openai` and then when I try to run it typing `openai`   I have the error: `openai : The term 'openai' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of    At line:1 char:1`.
But the installation is always successfull:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Collecting openai
  Using cached openai-0.11.0.tar.gz (150 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.20 in c:\users\igor\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from openai) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\igor\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from openai) (4.62.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.2.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from openai) (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas-stubs>=1.1.0.11 in c:\users\igor\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from openai) (1.2.0.38)
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl>=3.0.7 in c:\users\igor\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from openai) (3.0.9)       
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl>=3.0.7->openai) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.2.3->openai) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.2.3->openai) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.2.3->openai) (1.21.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\igor\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\igor\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tqdm->openai) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=1.2.3->openai) (1.16.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for openai, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: openai
    Running setup.py install for openai ... done
Successfully installed openai-0.11.0
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

I had this issue on powershell and on git bash either.

Comment: Is `openai` supposed to be a runnable command once you install it via pip? Usually modules have to be imported in Python via `import openai` or whatever, so unless there's some documentation that says that running the command "openai" is supposed to do something, then I'm not convinced this should work. Although if it is supposed to be a runnable command, that's usually caused by a Python PATH variable issue.

Comment: yeah, actually it is a runnable command. and I saw on some videos that it works just after install it with pip, but in all of the videos that I saw, the guys used it on bash, so, I tried it on git bash but it still going wrong and I don't know why